# ros2 crystal rqt_plot error: find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rqt_plot and having trouble. I noticed that there are a lot of these error messages generated when I'm trying to add a field to the plot:

```
$ ros2 run rqt_plot rqt_plot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/crystal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 256, in on_topic_edit_textChanged
    plottable, message = is_plottable(self._node, topic_name)
  File "/opt/ros/crystal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 151, in is_plottable
    fields, message = get_plot_fields(node, topic_name)
  File "/opt/ros/crystal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 135, in get_plot_fields
    slot_type, is_array, array_size = _parse_type(slot_type)
  File "/opt/ros/crystal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 57, in _parse_type
    end_array_idx = topic_type_str.find(']', start=array_idx + 1)
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

It seems that plot_widget.py expects `topic_type_str` to be of type `string`, but it's of type `str` instead. Am I missing some dependency? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323177/ros2-crystal-rqt_plot-error:-find()-takes-no-keyword-arguments/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It seems that plot_widget.py expects `topic_type_str` to be of type `string`, but it's of type `str` instead.

I'm not sure that's the problem: `str` is what `string` (if you're talking about the ROS2 idl type) is mapped to afaik in Python clients.

The last line in the traceback shows this:

```
topic_type_str.find(']', start=array_idx + 1)
```

`start` is a "keyword argument" here. That is not supported. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686971) on SO fi.

It seems to have been introduced in [ros-visualization/rqt_plot#17](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_plot/pull/17/files#diff-c8cb265550479f7ab3a9cc67852965dfR57) when `rqt_plot` was ported to ROS 2.

It looks like it's a copy-pasta or mistake (as it doesn't appear elsewhere in the file).

---

Submitted [ros-visualization/rqt_plot#29](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_plot/pull/29) to remove the `start` there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-05-15**:
Thanks for the response. I'll track the bug. Re: `string`, I was referring to the Python string module. But now I see that the string.find() method is not part of Python 3. So, a mis-formed question.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-05-15**:
I patched locally, and found 2 more bugs. Submitted https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_plot/pull/30 with all 3 fixes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
Ok.

Would've been nice to just base your PR on my commit, but nice to see things got fixed in the end.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-05-15**:
Whoops, my git foo is still weak. I'll work on that next time. Thanks again.